# SQL Syntax error. Where is my syntatic mistake?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I can't for the life of me spot my typo!

```
UPDATE orders o, orders_total_couponz otc
    SET o.total_paid = o.total_paid - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    SET o.total_paid_tax_incl = o.total_paid_tax_incl - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    SET o.total_paid_tax_excl = o.total_paid_tax_excl - otc.converted_value,
    SET o.total_paid_tax_real = o.total_paid_tax_real - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    SET o.total_products = o.total_products - otc.converted_value,
    SET o.total_products_wt = o.total_products_wt - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) )
WHERE o.id_order = otc.orders_id
```

error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET o.total_paid_tax_incl = o.total_paid_tax_incl - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 ' at line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `set` keyword only once, and comma-separate the values to set:

```
UPDATE orders o, orders_total_couponz otc
SET o.total_paid = o.total_paid - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    o.total_paid_tax_incl = o.total_paid_tax_incl - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    o.total_paid_tax_excl = o.total_paid_tax_excl - otc.converted_value,
    o.total_paid_tax_real = o.total_paid_tax_real - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    o.total_products = o.total_products - otc.converted_value,
    o.total_products_wt = o.total_products_wt - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) )
WHERE o.id_order = otc.orders_id
```

Comment: oh lord.  That's what I get for doing copy/paste at 3am.  Thanks (and sorry)

Comment: That's okay. We've all been there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use SET again and again. Use command like:

```
UPDATE orders o, orders_total_couponz otc
    SET o.total_paid = o.total_paid - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
     o.total_paid_tax_incl = o.total_paid_tax_incl - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    o.total_paid_tax_excl = o.total_paid_tax_excl - otc.converted_value,
    o.total_paid_tax_real = o.total_paid_tax_real - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) ),
    o.total_products = o.total_products - otc.converted_value,
    o.total_products_wt = o.total_products_wt - ( otc.converted_value * ( 1 + ( otc.tax_rate / 100 ) ) )
WHERE o.id_order = otc.orders_id
```